# How to join animated/inanimate object without BOTH animating?

Tags: animation

Sorry I don’t have a picture. Essentially, I animated a glass tube to spin around, but when I joined it with the larger object I made for it to go inside, the ENTIRE joined object spins. Is there a way to join them as a whole, yet have them animate separately?

Comment: Not sure why you need to join them... but the only way I can think of is to skin them to separate bones and animate one of them.

Comment: The reason is because I am making a robotic arm and the tube spins in the bicep of the arm. But thank you, I may try that

Comment: Ahh that makes perfect sense...

Comment: Instead of joining, cant you parent them? Sorry I'm unable to visualize properly. It would help if you can share your file here.